# form method="POST" generating GET request? Spring / JSP

Tags: forms, spring, jsp

I have a jsp page with the following form tag:

```
<form:form method='POST' action="index.htm" commandName='filterForm'>
```

then in my controller class I have the following:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void data(FilterForm form, BindingResult errors, ModelMap model)
{
...
}
```

when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/test/data.htm', method 'GET', ....
```

how come it's trying to do a GET when the method is set to POST ??
I'm a bit new at this so perhaps I have missed something obvious but it's driving me buggy. If I intercept the GET request using a 3rd party app and change it to POST then the above java method gets executed so that part works.

Answer (score 1):

Your uri also differs (index.html / data.htm). Make sure this is the same request.

Even if it's the same request, the `data(..)` method should then return a view. If it doesn't (void), e default view (likely `data.htm`) is attempted, which may not exist. By default the view is resolved via forward, but depending on the method body and on configuration it may be redirected.

Comment: but if I change the method=RequestMethod.POST to .GET then it works and I don't get the above mentioned error so it seems as if almost the form method POST is being ignored or set somewhere else but no idea where or how

Comment: is there a proxy? It might change that

Comment: the form submit button was making an ajax call which had method set to GET. Chalk a fail up for me :)